# Python convert epoch time to day or night with date

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I'm really new to python. I have a dataset containing epoch time and want to create two new columns(one for Date and another one for Shift(Day or night[6 AM-6 PM belongs to Day and 6 PM to 6 AM belongs to NIGHT])).
Heres my data frame:

[image]

What I required:

[image]

Comment: What did you search for, and what did you find? What did you try, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [23]: df
Out[23]:
     ID        time
0  1001  1592290638
1  1001  1592290649
2  1001  1592290659

In [24]: df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],unit='s').dt.strftime("%d %b")

In [25]: df["Shift"] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],unit='s').apply(lambda x: "Day" if x.hour >= 6 and x.hour <= 18 else "Night")

In [26]: df
Out[26]:
     ID        time    Date Shift
0  1001  1592290638  16 Jun   Day
1  1001  1592290649  16 Jun   Day
2  1001  1592290659  16 Jun   Day
```